# Add HTML to the bottom of each post in a post list

Tags: filters, hooks

In a listing of posts I'd like to add some HTML to the bottom of each post.

What hook should I use?

I have used the function below which is working nicely for each single page, but when I remove the is_single then I just get the results at the end of the block but I want the results after each post in the loop. Should I use "the_post"?

```
function add_single_post_content($content) {

   $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
   $organisation_name = get_field('organisation_name', 'user_'. $author_id );

   if (is_single()) { 
    $content .= '<p><div id="content-creator">Author: ' .get_field('content_creator') .' </div></p>
                 <p><div id="organisation-name">Organisation Name: ' .$organisation_name .' </div></p>';
    }
   return $content;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'add_single_post_content', 0);
```

Comment: Your theme may have hooks at the end of the loop to tap into. What theme are you using. And what do you mean by _"..at the end of the block"_ ?

Comment: Thanks David. I am using Impreza, and I couldn't see any hooks, but I have now realised that the looping of the posts was coming from a Visual Composer Datagrid on a static page rather than a usual post type page. I meant that the code was coming after all the posts had looped